# MS PowerPoint: how to convert a shape's position and size into screen coordinates?

Tags: powerpoint, shapes, pixel

I wrote me a little VBA Macro for PowerPoint (2010) that opens a popup with explanations when hovering over some Shape. This works fine. Alas, there is no event that is triggered when leaving the area again and so I now want to extend the code such that it monitors the area of the popup and when the pointer leaves that area it removes the popup again.

But now I ran into some stupid problem: the coordinates of the Shape (.Left, .Top, .Width, and .Height) are given in some "document units" (don't know exactly what unit this is in). The pointer coordinates, however, are obviously in screen pixels. To be able to reasonably compare the two to calculate whether the pointer is inside or outside I need to first convert the Shape's dimensions into screen pixels.

I googled around a lot, but while I found several at first promising code snippets, none of these worked (as most were for Excel and PowerPoint obviously has a different document model).

Could some kind soul give me a hint or some reference how to convert a Shape's dimension into screen pixels (i.e. taking scaling, window position, zoom-factor etc. into account).

M.

Comment: Any pointers where to start for to detect the mouse over events?

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone's interested - here is my solution after LOTS of further googling:

```
Type POINTAPI
   x As Long
   y As Long
End Type

Type Rectangle
    topLeft As POINTAPI
    bottomRight As POINTAPI
End Type

Private Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
Private Declare Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hDC As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hDC As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function ClientToScreen Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long

Private Function TransformShape(osh As Shape) As Rectangle
    Dim zoomFactor As Double
    zoomFactor = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.zoom / 100

    Dim hndDC&
    hndDC = GetDC(0)
    Dim deviceCapsX As Double
    deviceCapsX = GetDeviceCaps(hndDC, 88) / 72 ' pixels per pt horizontal (1 pt = 1/72')
    Dim deviceCapsY As Double
    deviceCapsY = GetDeviceCaps(hndDC, 90) / 72 ' pixels per pt vertical (1 pt = 1/72')

    With TransformShape
        ' calculate:
        .topLeft.x = osh.Left * deviceCapsX * zoomFactor
        .topLeft.y = osh.Top * deviceCapsY * zoomFactor
        .bottomRight.x = (osh.Left + osh.width) * deviceCapsX * zoomFactor
        .bottomRight.y = (osh.Top + osh.height) * deviceCapsY * zoomFactor
        ' translate:
        Dim lngStatus As Long
        lngStatus = ClientToScreen(hndDC, .topLeft)
        lngStatus = ClientToScreen(hndDC, .bottomRight)
    End With

    ReleaseDC 0, hndDC
End Function

...
Dim shapeAsRect As Rectangle
shapeAsRect = TransformShape(someSape)

Dim pointerPos As POINTAPI
Dim lngStatus As Long
lngStatus = GetCursorPos(pointerPos)

If ((pointerPos.x <= shapeAsRect.topLeft.x) Or (pointerPos.x >= shapeAsRect.bottomRight.x) Or _
    (pointerPos.y <= shapeAsRect.topLeft.y) Or (pointerPos.y >= shapeAsRect.bottomRight.y)) Then
    ' outside:
    ...
Else ' inside
    ...
End If
...
```

Answer (score 0):

> > the coordinates of the Shape (.Left, .Top, .Width, and .Height) are given in some "document units" (don't know exactly what unit this is in).

Points.  72 points to the inch.

```
Sub TryThis()
    Dim osh As Shape
    Set osh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
    With ActiveWindow
        Debug.Print .PointsToScreenPixelsX(.Left)
        Debug.Print .PointsToScreenPixelsY(.Top)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Alas, this doesn't work. I always get an "Illegal Value" error. It seems, that during slideshow mode there is no ActiveWindow. So I tried to use ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow instead but that object doesn't have any .PointsToScreenPixelsX/Y method. Any ideas?

Comment: You can still get there.  Slideshow view will fill the screen with your slide.  WIN API calls can give you the screen resolution or if you control the PC, you can hardcode it, so it's a matter of ratios; you know the position/size of the shape on the slide, you know that the 10" width of the slide becomes 1024 or howevermany pixels on screen, so it's just ratios from there.  Gets a bit trickier if your slide show proportions don't match the screen proportions, but that just adds a step or to to the calculations.

Comment: No! NO! We don't do such brittle bricolage that works on exactly one machine but not another. NO WAY!