# Switch between different slides with a mouse click

Tags: vba, powerpoint, mouse

I want by clicking with the mouse on slide number 5 automatically (without clicking an object) go to slide number 2 during presentation,for example.
I need to do this on a few slides in the presentation that will return to the same slide everyone.
I searched all kinds of places and also here in the forum but did not find a solution that works.

Comment: Consider using APi functions, you'll find more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29758475/how-to-record-mouse-clicks-in-excel-vba) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31055297/powerpoint-or-excel-vba-capture-coordinates-of-mouse-click).

Comment: For navigating inside a presentation use Hyperlinks, but I don’t understand "I want by clicking...." ... "without clicking" part. Please edit your question and explain with some print screens

Comment: It means that instead the presentation being chronological 1,2,3,4,5 it would be 1,2,4 for example.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at PowerPoint's Custom Show feature (**Slide Show>Custom Slide Show**). You can choose an arbitrary selection of slides, then display them in any preferred order. No programming required.